# How to check if arguments are correct using Perl?

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl and I try to check if my 2 arguments starts with "-" or "--". My code:

```
if ($ARGV[0] ~= /^-*/ || $ARGV[1] ~= /^-*/) {
```

But when the arguments are "abc abc" it still passes the condition.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just as an advise: use module perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html. It will take some more time to learn how to use them the first time, but then it'll save you a lot of hassle... :-)

Comment: Indeed, take a peek at [Getopt::Long](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Getopt::Long). It's simpler to use than even a trivial reinventing of the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the [binding operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators) is `=~`, not `~=`. It's easy to remember, as it has a counterpart - `!~` (mean 'doesn't match'). But that's a simple typo.

What's more important, however, is the approach itself: if you want to match for `'-'` and `'--'`, the pattern should be written as `/^--?/`. It's not clear, however, whether or not you consider `'---abc'` a valid argument. If not, the regex should look like the following:

```
/^--?[^-]+$/
```

... otherwise it's enough just to check the first character of the corresponding param against '-', and using regex is clearly an overkill. For example:

```
if (substr($ARGV[0], 0, 1) eq '-' || substr($ARGV[1], 0, 1) eq '-') {
  # invalid params detected
}
```

Still, the way you tried to implement it, it should have been written as `/^-+/`, not `/^-*/`. The last one matches for *any* number of hyphens at the start of the string - including 0 hyphens. That's why `abc` string passed the check. In fact, *any* string would have passed the check.

Comment: I think || is ok because I check if any of 2 arguments starts with - and if it does I print warning and exit (I want only arguments without - or --). Now I have something like this: if ($ARGV[0] ~= /^--?/ || $ARGV[1] ~= /^--?/) { but the compiler throws syntax error beetwen ] ~ (syntax error at ./translate.pl line 26, near "] ~")

Comment: Because it should be `=~`, not `~=`.